# What the differnce between mysql date defined as String and wrapped by "date()"?

Tags: mysql, date

I have pretty basic query:

```
SELECT count(*)  FROM myTable WHERE report_date='2013-12-01';
```

Result:

```
 100
```

On other hand followed example gives me other result (with offset of 1)

```
SELECT count(*)  FROM myTable WHERE date(report_date) = '2013-12-01';
```

Result:

```
 101 // Hmmm
```

Please help,

Thanks,

**[EDIT]**

`report_date` has a Type of `datetime`

Comment: select `report_date` for both queries and compare. PS: what type is it?

Comment: Maybe one of your record has timestamp in the `report_date` column. So it is not matched when exact string match is performed with `2013-12-01`. Whereas when you explicitly use `DATE()` then only date part is matched and timestamp is ignored.

Comment: Your `report_date` is not a `DATE` (probably a `DATETIME` or a `TIMESTAMP`)

Comment: @ypercube I edited my question, please see above

Comment: @ypercube: Actually, MySQL has implicit conversion feature. This is mostly applied when explicit cast is not done. But, I could not find a documented resource on this point.

Comment: @Ravinder I know. The problem is that conversion to DATE (in the 2nd query) will cut off the time part. In the first query, the '2013-12-01' is converted to DATETIME and the `report_date` has a time part (for this one row that makes the difference)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from the why, which is already explained by others, the best possible and most index-friendly way to query for date ranges on a column with the time component is

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  
  FROM myTable 
  WHERE report_date >= :start_date
    AND report_date <  :end_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18ea9/4)** demo

**Don't use any functions** (e.g. `DATE()`) on the left side of a condition in a `WHERE` clause like in your example

```
WHERE date(report_date) = '2013-12-01'
```

By doing so you prevent MySQL from using any index(indices) you may have created on this column effectively causing a full scan.

Do all necessary transformation on the right side applying them to the constant (parameter) values.

---

Recommended reading:

- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) by @AaronBertrand

Answer (score 3):

If `report_date` is a `DATETIME` or a `TIMESTAMP` it contains a time part (which defaults to 0:00). If you have one record for which the value is '2013-12-01 3:42:00' then the comparison `report_date = '2013-12-01'` will fail because the string on the right hand side converts to '2013-12-01 0:00:00' which is not '2013-12-01 3:42:00'.

If you apply `DATE`, then you will get `DATE('2013-12-01 3:42:00') = '2013-12-01'` and the record will be included in the resultset.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one of your record has timestamp part other that `00:00:00` in the report_date column. So it is not matched when match is performed with `2013-12-01`. Whereas when you explicitly use DATE() then only date part is matched and timestamp is ignored

**Working Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae63a/4**